# Masstransit: difference between routing slip activities and saga activites

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to understand what is the difference between a routing slip activity and a saga activity. When should I use one and when should I use the other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State machine activities are meant to encapsulate business logic, and allow for dependency injection during event handling. Other than that, they have no special behavior.

Routing slip activities are composed into a routing slip, which is a form of distributed transaction. If subsequent activities in a routing slip fault, completed activities are compensated. You can read all about it [in the blog post introducing it](http://blog.phatboyg.com/masstransit/2013/03/28/implementing-routing-slip-with-masstransit.html) (yes, Courier has been in MassTransit since 2013).